# Immutable javascript with direct property access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, immutable.js

I'm implementing [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) in a set of [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) components with props containing objects, where Immutable has not been used before.

While I was rewriting all *{ someProp.someValue }* to *{ someProp.get("someValue") }* (since Immutable don't have the props directly accessable), I am just wondering if it could have been possible to have the object properties directly accessable while the object is still immutable.

I guess the reason is that if they where directly accessable, they would be mutable because that's how javascript objects work. However, could it not be possible to [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) the objects (in browsers supporting it of course), and still have the mutating methods (.set, .map etc) create copies instead of changing the object itself the way Immutable work?

Is that technically possible, and is there any library doing something like this allready?

Comment: you can freeze a plain object and access it normally. you could also create a wrapper around your immutable structure, using Object.defineProperty to make getters that call .get() internally.

Answer (score 0):

"Is that technically possible"

Yes, the implementation you described would solve that particular problem, but Immutable does more than just provide data structures you're not allowed to change directly:

> `Immutable` provides Persistent Immutable `List`, `Stack`, `Map`, `OrderedMap`, `Set`, `OrderedSet` and `Record`. They are **highly efficient on modern JavaScript VMs by using structural sharing via hash maps tries and vector tries as popularized by Clojure and Scala, minimizing the need to copy or cache data**.
>
> `Immutable` also provides a lazy `Seq`, **allowing efficient chaining of collection methods like `map` and `filter` without creating intermediate representations.** Create some `Seq` with `Range` and `Repeat`.

Emphasis mine.

So, if you have a huge set of nested immutable Maps and Lists, and you change one element (that is: you create a *new* structure with mostly the same data but one item different), Immutable will be able to share a lot of the data between the two data structures, making the operation faster and consuming less memory.

However, this means that the `someValue` value isn't necessarily stored at the top of the data structure, waiting for you to access it; Immutable has to reach into internals to find it for you, thus the need for `get`.

I suspect you could create a very cool and friendly API using [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) (to hide the underlying data structures) and [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (to intercept proprety accessors), but [browser support is practically non-existent](http://caniuse.com/#feat=proxy).

---

"and is there any library doing something like this already?"

The closest thing I can think of at the moment is [React's immutable helpers](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html). The update syntax is a bit noisy in order to support a wide range of operations, but what you get out the other end is are plain JavaScript objects and arrays.

> Dealing with immutable data in JavaScript is more difficult than in languages designed for it, like Clojure. However, we've provided a simple immutability helper, `update()`, that makes dealing with this type of data much easier, ***without* fundamentally changing how your data is represented**.

The helper sort of *assumes* the objects you're passing in are implicitly immutable, but there's no reason you couldn't [deeply freeze](https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze) them as well.

Comment: More on Proxies: there is a very tiny and young [lib](https://github.com/Legitcode/immutable-proxy) for it - a good place to start.

Also, there is a [limited yet efficient polyfill for Proxies](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill)